# Pass data from POST route to template

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I am trying to build simple weather app using node.js. I want to display weather information in the separate ejs file.

My code in post route looks like this:

```
app.post('/', (req, res) => {

   var address = req.body.address;

    location.getLocation(address, (error, results) => {
     if(error) {
         console.log(error);
     } else {
     fetchWeather.getWeather(results.latitude, results.longitude, (error, 
     weatherResults) => {
    if(error){
      console.log(error);
    } else {
      var temp = weatherResults.temperature;
      var appTemp = weatherResults.apparentTemperature;
      console.log(temp, appTemp);
    }
  });
 }
});
res.redirect('weatherinfo');
});
```

I am using request to get data in seperate file :

```
    var getWeather = (lat, lng, callback) => {

      request({
      url:`https://api.darksky.net/forecast/mycode/${lat},${lng}
      ?units=si`,
      json: true
       }, (error, response, body) => {
         if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
          callback(undefined, {

          temperature: body.currently.temperature,
          apparentTemperature: body.currently.apparentTemperature
       });
      } else {
     callback('Unable to fetch weather.');
   }
 });
```

};

How can I export temperature and apparentTemperature to my ejs file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the temperature data to the view as variables:

```
app.post('/', (req, res) => {

    var address = req.body.address;

    location.getLocation(address, (error, results) => {
        if(error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            fetchWeather.getWeather(results.latitude, results.longitude, (error, weatherResults) => {
                if(error){
                    console.log(error);
                } else {
                    var temp = weatherResults.temperature;
                    var appTemp = weatherResults.apparentTemperature;


                    res.render('pages/yourFile.ejs, {
                        temp: temp,
                        appTemp: appTemp
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

and use them in your ejs file:

```
<p><%= temp %></p>
<p><%= appTemp %></p>
```

Comment: If i add appTemp i get error appTemp is not defind. Also, nothing is displayed in ejs when i put <p><%= temp %></p>

Comment: Did you set EJS as your view engine? `app.set('view engine', 'ejs');`. Also make sure that your temp and appTemp are defined before render the view: `console.log('temp:', temp, 'app temp:', appTemp)`

Comment: @JKshort I've updated my answer. The problem is that `getWeather ` is async so you need to render the view inside the callback.

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use something like [express-session](https://github.com/expressjs/session) you can store your data in `req.session` object, and then use it in your file

If you don't need to have persistency across user session, you can store data in res.locals, which are recognized by most express view engines, for example [EJS](http://www.ejs.co):

```
res.locals.temp = temp;
res.render('temp');
```

temp.ejs:

```
<% if (temp) { %>
  <h2><%= temp %></h2>
<% } %>
```